# Implementando filtro usando JPA

Tags: java, spring-jpa, jpql

Estou tentando implementar um filtro. Caso não passe nenhum parâmetro a requisição irá retornar todas as referências. Caso envie algum ou todos os parâmetros, a requisição irá retornar as referências com base no que foi informado.

```html
@Query(
            "FROM Users u " +
            "WHERE (:name IS NULL OR :name = '' OR LOWER(u.name) LIKE(CONCAT('%', :name, '%'))) " +
            "AND ((COALESCE(:initialDate, NULL) IS NULL OR u.dateOfBirth >= :initialDate)" +
                "OR (COALESCE(:finalDate, NULL) IS NULL OR u.dateOfBirth <= :finalDate)) " +
            "AND (:gender IS NULL OR :gender = '' OR u.gender = :gender) " +
            "AND (:publicPlace IS NULL OR :publicPlace = '' OR LOWER(u.publicPlace) LIKE(CONCAT('%', :publicPlace, '%'))) " +
            "AND (:number IS NULL OR u.number = :number) " +
            "AND (:district IS NULL OR :district = '' OR LOWER(u.district) LIKE(CONCAT('%', :district, '%'))) " +
            "AND (:city IS NULL OR :city = '' OR LOWER(u.city) LIKE(CONCAT('%', :city, '%'))) " +
            "AND (:state IS NULL OR u.state = :state)"
    )
    Page<User> filterUser(
            Pageable pageable,
            @Param("name") String name,
            @Param("initialDate") LocalDate initialDate,
            @Param("finalDate") LocalDate finalDate,
            @Param("gender") Character gender,
            @Param("publicPlace") String publicPlace,
            @Param("number") Integer number,
            @Param("district") String district,
            @Param("city") String city,
            @Param("state") State state
    );
```

O problema é que estou recebendo o erro

> [ERRO: operador não existe: character = smallint
> Dica: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> Posição: 687] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

- Acredito que esse erro esteja relacionado ao fato de estar usando Character.
- Não há opções de alterar para String, uma vez que foi requisitado usar Character.

Alguém pode me ajudar?